# Display input with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to display the text that the user types inside the input with the name=ime after i click on the button.

```
<body>
Registracija
<form name='vnos' method='post' action='index.php'>     
Vnesi ime <input type="text" name="ime">
<br><br>
<button type="button" name='tipka'>Pritisni me</button>
</form>  
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["tipka"]))
    {
    echo $_POST['ime'];
    }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Well then, display it. what's the problem?

Comment: are you looking to maintain the input value? ie. `<input type="text" name="ime" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["tipka"]))  { echo $_POST['ime']; } ?>" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong type for the button here:

```
<button type="button" name='tipka'>Pritisni me</button>
```

it needs to be a submit type

```
<button type="submit" name='tipka'>Pritisni me</button>
```

`button` type only works with JS (Javascript).

**Note:** Make sure you're using this off a webserver and with the right protocol such as `http://localhost/file.php` or hosted which is unknown, and not as `file:///` directly into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<body>
Registracija
<form name='vnos' method='post' action=''>
Vnesi ime <input type="text" name="ime">
<br><br>
<button type="submit" name='tipka'>Pritisni me</button>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['tipka']))
    {
        echo $_POST['ime'];
    }
?>
</body>
```